# Get USSD codes reques text in android

Tags: android, call, ussd

[Edit]
i want to retrieve USSD code result text,how can do it?

for example : after calling *12345*1# my device show a popup message for me, i want to get that text.

can anyone help me?

Comment: how can server show text? what you exacty required?

Comment: for example i calling *140*1# in my country and my phone show my remaining money of my simcard to me, i need that text.

Comment: i mean is, the ussd request resault popup text.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of someone doing that kind of task in this github project:
https://github.com/alaasalman/ussdinterceptor.git

The code shows a broadcast receiver you can use in your application to receive the result of USSD code requests.